# Why is $\Delta V = - \int E \cdot dr$ when charge is moving from lower potential to higher potential?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, potential-energy, conventions

In a parallel plate capacitor, charge $q$ is travelling from negative to positive plate. Why is $\Delta V$ negative? Every book explains it by saying $\Delta U = -W$,  but this equation came when we assumed that particle was travelling from higher potential to lower potential.

Comment: Going from the negative plate to positive plate  change in V is positive as you are going against the electric field lines, $\int E.dl$ from negative plate to positive plate is negative  so multiplying  by a negative gives a positive. you are confusing potential and potential energy, for a negative charge moving through a positive Pd, the potential ENERGY decreases as U = qV so if q is negative then the potential energy Is getting MORE negative

Comment: electrons move from low potential to high potential. protons move from high to low potential. however both move from high to low potential ENERGY

Answer (score 1):

The expression
$$
\Delta U_F = -W_F
$$
is the *definition* of the potential energy function for a conservative force; no assumptions are being made here.  Then the *definition* of the change in potential is
$$
\Delta V = \frac{\Delta U_{F_E\text{ on }q_{\rm test}}}{q_{\rm test}}
$$
So, to find the potential difference in an electric field, you must determine the potential energy difference experienced by a test charge, which, in turn, is found by the work done by the electric force on that test charge.  In summary:
\begin{align}
\Delta V \left(\vec{r}_1 \rightarrow \vec{r}_2\right) &= \frac{\Delta U_{F_E \text{ on } q_{\rm test}} \left(\vec{r}_1 \rightarrow \vec{r}_2\right)}{q_{\rm test}}\\
 & = \frac{- W_{F_E \text{ on } q_{\rm test}} \left(\vec{r}_1 \rightarrow \vec{r}_2\right)}{q_{\rm test}}\\
 & = - \frac{1}{q_{\rm test}} \int_{\vec{r}_1 \rightarrow \vec{r}_2} \vec{F}_{E}\left(\vec{r}\right) \cdot d\vec{r}\\
& = - \frac{1}{q_{\rm test}} \int_{\vec{r}_1 \rightarrow \vec{r}_2} q_{\rm test} \, \vec{E}\left(\vec{r}\right) \cdot d\vec{r}\\
& = -  \int_{\vec{r}_1 \rightarrow \vec{r}_2} \vec{E}\left(\vec{r}\right) \cdot d\vec{r}\\
& = - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec{E}\left(\vec{r}(t)\right) \cdot \frac{{\rm d} \vec{r}}{{\rm d} t}(t) \,dt\\
\end{align}
where the last expression is the meaning of the line integral, with $\vec{r}(t)$ a chosen parameterized path along the curve from $\vec{r}_1$ to $\vec{r}_2$. So the expression you wrote down for $\Delta V$ is completely general.

For the specific case of two (infinite) parallel-plate capacitors separated by $d$, the electric field is uniform, and we can choose a straight path, perpendicular to the plates. If you want to find $\Delta V_{\text{neg to pos}}$, then along this path $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{v}$ is negative, so:
\begin{align}
\Delta V &= - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec{E}\left(\vec{r}(t)\right) \cdot \frac{{\rm d} \vec{r}}{{\rm d} t}(t) dt\\
&= + E \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{{\rm d} x}{{\rm d} t}(t) \, dt\\
&= E \int_{x_{\rm neg}}^{x_{\rm pos}} {\rm d} x \\
&= E d
\end{align}
The result is positive, as it should be because the positive plate, $V_f$, is at a higher potential than the negative plate, $V_i$.

If you decided to calculate $\Delta V_{\text{pos to neg}}$, you would find a negative answer.

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign in front of the integral will ensure that $\Delta V$ is positive in this case. The $\vec{E}$ between the plates of the capacitor points from the positively charged plate toward the negatively charged plate. If you're moving a charge from the negative plate to the positive plate, the $d\vec{r}$ points in the opposite direction of $\vec{E}$. So the dot product, $\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{r}$ is negative ($\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r} = Edr\cos\theta$ but $\theta = 180^\circ$ so $\cos\theta = -1$). Then the minus sign in front of the integral will make the result positive, as it should be when you move against the direction of the electric field.

Answer (score 0):

Many forces $\vec{F}$ can be written as the gradient of some potential $V$. For example the force exerted to a particle of charge $q$ due to a potential $V$ is:
$$\vec{F}=-q\,\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\,V \tag{1}$$
Note that $\vec{E}=-\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\,V$.

Because of the definition of this force, the potential $V$ is defined up to a constant. Set this constant without any loss of generality to $0$.

It is clear that the system in which this force is exerted, evolves until equilibrium of forces, $\textit{i.e.}$ $\vec{F}=0$ and there is no motion.

This stable equilibrium point can be reached only when the function $V$ has a minimum as you can see from $(1)$. Therefore the system always goes from high to low potential when no additional forces are exerted.

The work done by this particle through a curve $C$ is then:
$$W=\int_{C}{\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}}=-q\int_{C}{\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\,V\cdot d\vec{r}} =-q\Delta V$$

Where $\Delta V$ is the total difference between the values of the potential evaluated at the extrema of the curve $C$.